# How to lay out the conversion of £ $(13 + v^{2}/52)$ per hour to £ per mile

Tags: unit-of-measure

"**29.** The total running cost of a ship per hour is £ (13 + $v^{2}$/52) where $v$ knots is the speed. if £ $C$ is the cost per nautical mile, write down an equation expressing $C$ in terms of $v$..."

So, we know the cost in £ h$^{-1}$. We need the cost in £ mi$^{-1}$. Additionally, the cost is expressed in terms of $v$ which is given in units of mi h$^{-1}$.

On the face of it, I thought (and I haven't got much experience of doing this), all I have to do is divide by $v$ mi h$^{-1}$:

$\dfrac{\text{£}\,x\ \text{h}^{-1}}{y \text{ mi h}^{-1}} = \text{£}\,z\text{ mi}^{-1}$

This gives the right answer:

$$\frac{13}{v} + \frac{v}{52}$$

But I don't know how to lay it out. I know the question says "write down" - but if only for own benefit, I'd still like to know how to do it nicely.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "lay it out". Your idea of looking at the dimensions to get the answer is a good one.

Comment: Well I just mean, say I don't want to do it in my head and I'd like to write it out on a piece of paper, how should I show my working - is there an accepted format for these kind of questions?